# Как сделать груповую проверку форму в Symfony 4.4.8?

Tags: php7, symfony4

Возник вопрос: у меня есть такая форма

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url;
/**
 * Class CommonFieldType
 * Implements adjacent fields for the short link form and the file upload form
 * @package App\Form
 */
class CommonFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('url',TextType::class,['constraints' => new Url()])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

В Symfony есть стандартный фильтр для проверки url

> Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Url

Что бы его использовать я пишу

> ['constraints' => new Url()]

Но мне нужно проверить еще максимальную длину как это сделать? 
Есть такой способ

> ['constraints' => new Length(['max' => 255])]

Но так же поле еще может быть пустым
Но как мне объединить эти три проверки? 
То есть условие проверки формы: если не пустая проверить на валидность url и на длину
В офицальной документации сказано

> If you are using validation groups, you need to either reference the
>   Default group when creating the form, or set the correct group on the
>   constraint you are adding: new NotBlank(['groups' => ['create',
>   'update']]);

Но если честно мне это вообще не помогло, подскажите как сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно указать несколько проверок.

```
->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
            new Length(['min' => 3]),
        ],
```